# While function not working in error handler - vba?

Tags: excel, error-handling, while-loop, vba

I have the following code extract, its opening a workbook however if it does not exist i want it to then find and open the latest file however its not working and just saying that it cant open the file with today's date?

Can someone please tell me where i am going wrong? :(

```
Sub test()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
Workbooks.Open Worksheets("Filenames").Range("A6").Value

Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
Dim dtTestDate As Date
Dim sStartWB As String

Const sPath As String = "I:\Transaction Reports\Supply Outlook Inputs\"
Const dtEarliest = #10/10/2015#

dtTestDate = Date
sStartWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name

While ActiveWorkbook.Name = sStartWB And dtTestDate >= dtEarliest
    On Error Resume Next
    Workbooks.Open sPath & "qryDAConsumption " & Format(dtTestDate, "DDMMYY") & ".xlsx"
    dtTestDate = dtTestDate - 1
    On Error GoTo 0
Wend

If ActiveWorkbook.Name = sStartWB Then MsgBox "Earlier file not found."

Dim wb8 As String
wb8 = ActiveWorkbook.Name

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Resume Next

Sheets("qryDAConsumption").Select
Cells.Copy
ThisWorkbook.Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your question:
 
While-Loops are working in Error-Handlers.

Your problem lies more within the way you try to achive your task. Errors should be the exception - not the main flow.

Why don't you check if the file even exists before you try to open it?
Something like this:

```
Dim fso as Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

if fso.FileExists(Worksheets("Filenames").Range("A6").Value) Then
    'open the file 
else
    'Search for the latest file in your folder
end if
```

Hope this will get you started into the right direction.

Greetings

Comment: Thanks for your help therak ill give this approach a shot!